# DB2 insert query

Tags: indexing, insert, db2, primary-key, where-clause

There is a table Application

`select * from Application where application_number='123456'` gives me the following

```
ID  Application_number           DATE        location

12  123456                       2015/05/01  UK

15  123456                      2015/05/02  US

18  123456                  2015/04/02  ASIA

58  123456                  2015/04/02  APAC
```

I want to insert row with ID as 54

Query formulated by me

```
INSERT INTO Application ( ID, Application_number) SELECT 54 as ID , application_number FROM Application WHERE application_number='123456'
```

Result should be

```
ID  Application_number      DATE        location

12  123456                  2015/05/01  UK

15  123456                  2015/05/02  US

18  123456                  2015/04/02  ASIA

58  123456                  2015/04/02  APAC

54  123456                  date and location doesnt matter
```

Gives me error

> One or more values in the INSERT statement, UPDATE statement, or
>   foreign key update caused by a DELETE statement are not valid because
>   the primary key, unique constraint or unique index identified by "1"
>   constrains table "CFTSDB.A" from having duplicate values for the index
>   key.  SQLSTATE=23505

Please can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you really need to insert this specific ID? Why?

Comment: You have 4 rows in your sample `WHERE application_number='123456'`, so your `INSERT` statement attempts to insert 4 rows with ID equal to 54.

Comment: @mustaccio Is there any other way to achieve what is required? How would i be able to modify my query according to the requirement? Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Your insert is

```
INSERT INTO 
    Application (ID, Application_number) 
SELECT 
    54 as ID, 
    application_number 
FROM Application 
WHERE application_number='123456'
```

If you execute only the SELECT part in there it probably returns something like this:

```
ID  | Application_number
----+-------------------
54  | 123456
54  | 123456
54  | 123456
54  | 123456
```

This means, your insert tries to insert 4 rows, all with the ID 54. This can not work since your ID is probably unique.

If you want to insert only one new record at the ID 54, you should do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO Application 
    (ID, Application_number) 
VALUES
    (54, '123456')
```